# ListView item value change when I swip screen..Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in unity. I create a project in unity where I bind some items in listview and in one item I use two different images and change on click the item. It's works fine..But when I go to other tab(or browser) and come back to unity then the item will change on it's default state..

[Default state of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKsuR.png)

[Changing state of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ZUJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you to implement the tabs switch.

An easy way to keep the button status is using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

```
// before click other tab
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BtnStatus", someitem.status);

// after come back
someitem.status = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BtnStatus", 0);
```